# Spring boot Application stuck at FINE: preRegister org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet@71f8b414 Tomcat:type=JspMonitor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, maven

I am running Spring boot application but application is hung on following line for forever:

```
FINE: preRegister org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet@71f8b414 Tomcat:type=JspMonitor,WebModule=//localhost/,name=jsp,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
```

and after 4 to 5 minutes app is showing below messange: It means process has expired.

```
Feb 29, 2020 1:39:27 PM org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase processExpires
FINE: Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1582963767353 sessioncount 0
```

Weird thing is this is only happening in Mac and Ubuntu platform: on windows application is working fine.

I cross checked access rights of project files and then give all 777 ( Read,Write,Execute) access to all files of project.

By the way pom.xml is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <name>auth</name>
    <description>auth</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- added by max -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.chen0040</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-magento-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.00</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- end added by max -->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And **jstack stacktrace** is as below:

```
  Pramod:tecspringboot_application pramod-jazz$ jstack 91892
2020-02-29 17:08:52
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (13.0.1+9 mixed mode, sharing):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007f894c1a6a60, length=11, elements={
0x00007f894a067000, 0x00007f894a06a000, 0x00007f894b82a000, 0x00007f894a806000,
0x00007f894a06c000, 0x00007f894a06d000, 0x00007f894a816800, 0x00007f894b802800,
0x00007f894b11e000, 0x00007f894c828000, 0x00007f894b808000
}

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 cpu=0.45ms elapsed=10386.87s tid=0x00007f894a067000 nid=0x3e03 waiting on condition  [0x000070000facc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@13.0.1/Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@13.0.1/Reference.java:241)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@13.0.1/Reference.java:213)

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 cpu=0.19ms elapsed=10386.87s tid=0x00007f894a06a000 nid=0x4803 in Object.wait()  [0x000070000fbcf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@13.0.1/Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007d4f6f610> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@13.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        - locked <0x00000007d4f6f610> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@13.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@13.0.1/Finalizer.java:170)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 cpu=6.29ms elapsed=10386.86s tid=0x00007f894b82a000 nid=0xa903 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 cpu=1045.46ms elapsed=10386.86s tid=0x00007f894a806000 nid=0xa803 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C1 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 cpu=749.99ms elapsed=10386.86s tid=0x00007f894a06c000 nid=0x5803 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"Sweeper thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 cpu=11.73ms elapsed=10386.86s tid=0x00007f894a06d000 nid=0x5a03 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 cpu=0.08ms elapsed=10386.82s tid=0x00007f894a816800 nid=0x5b03 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Common-Cleaner" #10 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 cpu=17.48ms elapsed=10386.81s tid=0x00007f894b802800 nid=0x9f03 in Object.wait()  [0x00007000102e4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@13.0.1/Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007d4f6ff48> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@13.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        - locked <0x00000007d4f6ff48> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@13.0.1/CleanerImpl.java:148)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@13.0.1/Thread.java:830)
        at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@13.0.1/InnocuousThread.java:134)

"JPS event loop" #11 prio=5 os_prio=31 cpu=668.13ms elapsed=10386.24s tid=0x00007f894b11e000 nid=0x9a03 runnable  [0x00007000105ed000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.KQueue.poll(java.base@13.0.1/Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@13.0.1/KQueueSelectorImpl.java:122)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@13.0.1/SelectorImpl.java:124)
        - locked <0x00000007daa16e78> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000007daa16e18> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@13.0.1/SelectorImpl.java:136)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:824)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:457)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@13.0.1/Thread.java:830)

"DestroyJavaVM" #14 prio=5 os_prio=31 cpu=1458.75ms elapsed=10384.93s tid=0x00007f894c828000 nid=0x2303 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #15 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 cpu=4.63ms elapsed=0.11s tid=0x00007f894b808000 nid=0x6107 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 cpu=324.39ms elapsed=10386.88s tid=0x00007f894a815800 nid=0x3c03 runnable  

"GC Thread#0" os_prio=31 cpu=20.51ms elapsed=10386.89s tid=0x00007f894a019800 nid=0x5103 runnable  

"GC Thread#1" os_prio=31 cpu=21.62ms elapsed=10386.35s tid=0x00007f894b9db800 nid=0x5e03 runnable  

"GC Thread#2" os_prio=31 cpu=14.59ms elapsed=10386.35s tid=0x00007f894a0ab800 nid=0x9d03 runnable  

"GC Thread#3" os_prio=31 cpu=8.89ms elapsed=10385.92s tid=0x00007f894a06f800 nid=0x9903 runnable  

"G1 Main Marker" os_prio=31 cpu=0.04ms elapsed=10386.89s tid=0x00007f894a020800 nid=0x3103 runnable  

"G1 Conc#0" os_prio=31 cpu=0.02ms elapsed=10386.89s tid=0x00007f894b004800 nid=0x4f03 runnable  

"G1 Refine#0" os_prio=31 cpu=0.08ms elapsed=10386.89s tid=0x00007f894a061000 nid=0x4d03 runnable  

"G1 Young RemSet Sampling" os_prio=31 cpu=1740.76ms elapsed=10386.89s tid=0x00007f894b015000 nid=0x3603 runnable  
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 cpu=5888.00ms elapsed=10386.83s tid=0x00007f894b020000 nid=0xa103 waiting on condition  

JNI global refs: 21, weak refs: 45
```

Comment: Can you take a thread dump (using `jstack <pid>`, for example) when things are stuck and add it to your question?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson -  Hi Andy , jstack stacktrace is attached

Comment: @AndyWilkinson -  I was confused about pid, so i used jps command on mac and noted pid against , RemoteMavenServer.. Is this tight?

Comment: That doesn’t look like the right process. It appears to be part of IDEA rather than your Spring Boot app. Which other processes does `jps` list?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - I have listed this jps command out put in question details, at very bottom.

Comment: None of those is obviously your app. It might be easier to identify in the output from `ps -A | grep java`.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - this time I used option you suggested and  jstack stacktrace is uopdated in details

Comment: That doesn’t look like a Spring boot app either.